# Stored procedure that compare value between 2 tables and if not match insert values to a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables clients old & clients new.

I have a column in each one called status, I want to create a stored procedure that if the status in old is different then new insert to a third table called `clientsChanges` the client ID from one table and the account status from a different table.

I thought of using an IF condition but it seems that I can't.

Here is what I made:

```
DECLARE @newStatus nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @oldStatus nvarchar(MAX);

SET @newStatus = (select accountstatus from ods.vtiger_account);
SET @oldStatus = (select accountstatus from Panda.vtiger_account);

-- Insert statements for procedure here
IF (@newStatus != @oldStatus)
    INSERT INTO Panda.vtiger_audit_status_change 
    VALUES ((SELECT accountid FROM Panda.vtiger_account),
            (SELECT accountstatus FROM Panda.vtiger_account), 
            (SELECT accountstatus FROM ods.vtiger_account), 
            GETUTCDATE())
```

The error I get is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

Can someone help?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Using MSSQL with SSMS

Comment: you can just join between the tables and insert into audit table in one go, using variables is a mistake because they only store one value

Comment: Ended up using CTE: 
WITH tmp AS
(
select DISTINCT ac.accountid as accountid,ac.accountstatus as newStatus,oac.accountstatus as oldStatus, ac.modifiedtime as DateInsert from ods.vtiger_account as ac
left join Panda.vtiger_account as oac on ac.accountid=oac.accountid
where oac.accountstatus!=ac.accountstatus
group by ac.accountid,ac.accountstatus,oac.accountstatus,ac.modifiedtime
) 
insert into Panda.vtiger_audit_status_change (accountid, new_Status, old_status, modified_date) select * from tmp

Comment: Since you have `where oac` that doesn't make sense as a left join because you have effectively converted it to an inner join. The distinct is also suspicious.

Comment: This is obviously broken from the very beginning. You are setting a scalar variable to the result of a query and that query has no where clause. That means it will have the value of the last row in the result set. Adding more confusion to that, you have no order by so you have no idea which row will be "last". Also....do you really need nvarchar(max) for a status? Do you have a value that is more than 2,000 characters?

Comment: You are trying to assign the result of a table to a variable.  Of course it won't work.

Comment: RBMSes are set-based. i.e.: `EXCEPT` is a thing, ref: [Set Operators - EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?)